# How to pass a pointer to object method?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I'm trying to make a `CurlResponse` object encapsulating libcurl response. My implementation of curl options `WRITEFUNCTION` and `HEADERFUNCTION` is mostly the same, the only difference being that in first case I'm calling `response->appendBody` and in the second - `response->appendHeader`. I would like to have one function and pass a pointer to appropriate method as a parameter, e.g. `WRITEDATA` would be `response->appendBody`, and I could call `writer(data)`. However when I execute the below code, I get an error:

```
 error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘struct std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (CurlResponse::*)(std::basic_string<char>)>(CurlResponse*, std::_Placeholder<1>)>’ through ‘...’
```

...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

class CurlResponse {
    public:
        void appendBody(string data) {
            cout << "Append body " << data << endl;
        }

        void appendHeader(string data) {
            cout << "Append header " << data << endl;
        }
};

//size_t WriteMemoryCallback(char * contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, CurlResponse* response)
size_t WriteMemoryCallback(char * contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, function<void(string)> writer)
{
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  string data(contents, realsize);
//  response->appendBody(data);
  writer(data);
  return realsize;
}

size_t WriteHeaderCallback(char * contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, CurlResponse* response)
{
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  string data(contents, realsize);
  response->appendHeader(data);
  return realsize;
}

int main() {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (! curl) return 1;

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost");

    CurlResponse* response = new CurlResponse();

    auto writeBody = std::bind(&CurlResponse::appendBody, response, placeholders::_1);
    writeBody("Test writing to body");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, writeBody);
//  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, response);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, WriteHeaderCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, response);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return 0;
}
```

How do I fix this? Does this mean I can use `std::bind`ed functions in the same function, but can't pass them anywhere?

Comment: `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` is for specifying the argument of the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` or a file handle but you are trying to pass a function, why?

Comment: I'm trying to read the data into memory, specifically into one object representing all data curl got. Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to pass a complex object through `...`, as the compiler already tells you. The probably best solution is to first wrap the `std::bind` in a `std::function` object, to avoid having to repeat the complete type:

```
    function<void(string)> writeBodyPass(writeBody);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &writeBodyPass);
```

You then have to fix the signature (and body) of your callback, as you are now receiving a pointer to the `std::function` object:

```
size_t WriteMemoryCallback(char * contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, function<void(string)> *writer)
{
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  string data(contents, realsize);
  (*writer)(data);
  return realsize;
}
```

Comment: I've tried calling it like `&writeBody`, changed `writer` to `*writer` in `WriteMemoryCallback`, but now I can't call it - `‘writer’ cannot be used as a function`. BTW Curl api is in `WriteMemoryCallback` - the first 3 args are always the same, and the fourth is provided by WRITEDATA.

Comment: Had not seen the callback code yet, sorry. Okay, in that case, you also have to fix your argument types. You’re passing a pointer to a bind object, not to a function object. Once you fixed that, you can call it using ``(*writer)(data)``.

Comment: @Bob I edited my answer according to your feedback. Hoping that this works.

Comment: It seems to work, thanks. What is weird though, I can call it like `function<void(string)> writeBody = std::bind...` and it would still work, while with `auto writeBody = std::bind...` it does not. I thought `auto` is equal to the full type definition?

Comment: Yes it is equal, and thats the problem here: ``auto`` evaluates to a type involving an ``std::_Bind`` template (implementation detail; see your error message for the complete type). When you write ``function<..> foo = std::bind..``, a new ``function<..>`` object is constructed, by copying (and hiding) the ``std::bind`` contents, so that we have a normalized interface to a callable.